# Funcionamento do stack e do memory align no MASM X64

Tags: memória, assembly, stack, x64

Eu tenho uma aplicação que pega um código TAC (IL) e gera um código ASM usando x64 MASM. O problema é que eu não estou tendo erro nenhum de compilação, e sim, (pelo menos é o que eu acho) na hora de construir a *stack*. O programa abaixo é um MMC, então, se eu digitar 3 e 5 como entrada, ele deveria me retornar 15, mas ele está me retornando números aleatórios, como 1281237 e 230932811.

Eu sei que em x86, o alinhamento funciona em 4 bytes, e eu li em alguns lugares que em x64 deveria ser 16 bytes. Mas se eu colocar 16, eu fico com um erro de memória quando eu executo o mesmo, logo, eu estou alinhando em 8 bytes, mas isso pode estar errado, não tenho certeza, não existe quase nenhuma documentação sobre MASM64 disponíveis por ai.

```
extern ExitProcess:proc
extern printf:proc
extern scanf:proc

includelib kernel32.lib
includelib user32.lib
includelib msvcrt.lib
include invoke_macros.asm

.data
scan BYTE 'scanf:',0
formatInt BYTE '%d',0
msg BYTE 'Return = %d',0
printInt BYTE 'printf: %d', 0ah, 0h
f1  BYTE 'Fake parameter #1 ( 137 - 279 ):',0

.data?
din dq ?

.code

start PROC
invoke  printf, addr f1
invoke  scanf, addr formatInt, addr din
MOV rax, din
PUSH rax
CALL sub_411420
ADD rsp, 8
invoke printf, addr msg, rax
RET
start ENDP

sub_411B00 proc
PUSH rbp
MOV rbp, rsp
SUB rsp, 48
MOV rax, [rbp + 16]
MOV [rbp - 24], rax
MOV rax, [rbp + 12]
MOV [rbp - 16], rax
LABEL_1:
MOV rax, [rbp - 24]
MOV rbx, [rbp - 16]
CDQ
DIV rbx
MOV rax, rdx
MOV [rbp - 8], rax
MOV rax, [rbp - 16]
MOV [rbp - 24], rax
MOV rax, [rbp - 8]
MOV [rbp - 16], rax
MOV rax, [rbp - 8]
CMP rax, 0
JG LABEL_1
MOV rax, [rbp + 12]
MOV rbx, [rbp + 16]
MUL rbx
MOV rbx, [rbp - 24]
CDQ
DIV rbx
MOV [rbp - 48], rax
JMP LABEL_4
LABEL_4:
MOV eax, [rbp - 48]
ADD rsp, 48
POP rbp
RET
sub_411B00 endp

sub_411420 proc
PUSH rbp
MOV rbp, rsp
SUB rsp, 48
PUSH [rbp - 24]
invoke  printf, addr scan
invoke  scanf, addr formatInt, addr din
MOV rax, din
MOV [rbp - 24], rax
PUSH [rbp - 16]
invoke  printf, addr scan
invoke  scanf, addr formatInt, addr din
MOV rax, din
MOV [rbp - 16], rax
PUSH [rbp - 24]
PUSH [rbp - 16]
PUSH [rbp + 8]
CALL sub_411B00
MOV [rbp - 8], rax
PUSH [rbp - 8]
POP rax
invoke  printf, addr  printInt, rax
PUSH rax
MOV eax, [rbp - 8]
ADD rsp, 96
POP rbp
RET
sub_411420 endp

end
```

Então essa é a minha dúvida. Como que funciona o *stack* e o *memory align* em x64? Obrigado!

Comment: Editei o tópico Sérgio.

Comment: Acho que esse "nível" de pergunta será mais facilmente respondido no Stackoverflow em inglês. Tem um outro forum que parece ter bastante movimento por lá: http://masm32.com/board/index.php?board=13.0 .

Comment: @BernardoMeneghini comente esse código, meu jovem! Facilite a vida de quem vai te ajudar! :)

Comment: x86-64 não quebra o programa por acesso desalinhado, apenas roda mais lento. Por isso muitos programas em C rodam no x86/x86-64 e quebram quando são portados para ARM ou outras plataforma.s

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pode dar uma espiada nesse código:

https://github.com/osdeving/asm-snake

Você vai perceber que todas as stack-frames foram feitas manualmente, então você pode pegar algumas das funções que recebem parâmetros e/ou alocam espaço na pilha para variáveis locais e fazer algumas modificações no seu código pra se adequar.

P. ex.

```
;
; Função ListAppend.                                                                             ;
; Parâmetros: DWORD pList, DWORD x, DWORD y                                                      ;
; Retorno:    Retorna em EAX o início da lista.                                                  ;
; Descrição:  Anexa ao fim da lista.                                                             ;
;
ListAppend:
    PUSH EBP                         ; stack frame.   
    MOV EBP, ESP
    SUB ESP, 8                       ; Aloca espaço para dois ponteiros: new_list e last.
    
    PUSH 12                          ; dwBytes = 12 bytes.
    PUSH 0x0040                      ; uFlags = GPTR. 
    CALL [GlobalAlloc]
    MOV DWORD [EBP - 8], EAX         ; Guarda na variável local new_list.

etc...
```

Ser 64bits não vai mudar muita coisa com relação a maneira como você lida com a pilha. Acredito que pegando esse código com um uso mais 'cru' de variáveis locals, retornos, chamdas de funções, você consiga resolver seu problema. Esse trecho acima, p.ex., é a implementação de uma lista encadeada. O código que fiz tá muito bem comentado, bem fácil entender.

Espero ter ajudado, embora não tenha resolvido diretamente seu problema (teria que depurar seu código, e como tem muita diretiva do masm fica dificil fazer só no olhômetro.)